Is there software to cause a desktop pop up when someone answers a question of yours?
Or the windows notification facility, or something. I hate when comments go unanswered.

There are third-party browser extensions handling notifications for Chrome and Firefox. These create a desktop notification whenever an entry is added to your Stack Exchange inbox.
